# (Derived category of) sheaves over an infinite union

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

The short version of my question is:

Suppose $X$ is a (reasonably nice) topological space such that $X = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} X_n$ for an increasing sequence of (closed) subspaces $X_1 \subset X_2 \subset \cdots$​, and suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are sheaves on $X$ which are isomorphic when restricted to the $X_n$ (such that the isomorphisms are compatible when restricting along $X_n \hookrightarrow X_m$ for $m > n$). Then, is it true that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$​ are isomorphic?

Specifically, I am interested in the following scenario:

Let $G = \text{SU}(2)$ be the special unitary group, and let $\pi : EG \to BG$ be the universal bundle. Denote by $D^b(BG)$ the derived category of sheaves (of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces for simplicity) over $BG$. I am interested in the mapping cone $\mathcal{F} = \operatorname{Cone}(\underline{\mathbb{Q}} \to \pi_* \underline{\mathbb{Q}}) \in D^b(BG)$ where $\underline{\mathbb{Q}} \to \pi_* \underline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the non-trivial map in $\operatorname{Hom}(\underline{\mathbb{Q}}, \pi_* \underline{\mathbb{Q}}) = \operatorname{Hom}(\pi^{-1} \underline{\mathbb{Q}}, \underline{\mathbb{Q}}) = H^0(EG) = \mathbb{Q}$ (all pullbacks and pushforwards are derived). My suspicion is that $\mathcal{F}$ is equal to $\underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3]$, since their images under $\pi^{-1}$ and $(BG \to \text{pt})_*$ agree. My attempt to prove this is as follows:

As in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850108/classifying-space-bsun), we can take $EG = S^\infty = \operatorname{colim}_n S^{4n - 1}$ and $BG = S^\infty/S^3 = \operatorname{colim}_n (S^{4n - 1}/S^3) = \operatorname{colim}_n \mathbb{HP}^n = \mathbb{HP}^\infty$. Writing $i_n : \mathbb{HP}^n \to \mathbb{HP}^\infty$ for the inclusions and $\pi_n : S^{4n - 1} \to \mathbb{HP}^n$ for the projections, I claim that $i_n^{-1} \mathcal{F} = i^{-1}_n \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3] = \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3]$. Namely, applying $\operatorname{Hom}(-, \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3])$ to the triangle $i_n^{-1} \underline{\mathbb{Q}} \to i_n^{-1}\pi_* \underline{\mathbb{Q}} \to i_n^{-1} \mathcal{F} \xrightarrow{+}$, we find that $\operatorname{Hom}(i_n^{-1} \mathcal{F}, \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3]) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(i_n^{-1} \pi_* \underline{\mathbb{Q}}, \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3]) = \operatorname{Hom}((\pi_n)_! \underline{\mathbb{Q}}, \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3]) = \operatorname{Hom}(\underline{\mathbb{Q}}, \pi_n^! \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3]) = \operatorname{Hom}(\underline{\mathbb{Q}}, \underline{\mathbb{Q}}) = H^0(S^{4n - 1}) = \mathbb{Q}$, using that the relative dualizing sheaf is $\pi_n^! \underline{\mathbb{Q}} = \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[\dim(S^{4n -1}) - \dim(\mathbb{HP}^n)] = \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[3]$ as both $S^{4n - 1}$ and $\mathbb{HP}^n$ are smooth and orientable. So there is a non-trivial map $i_n^{-1} \mathcal{F} \to \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3]$. To show it is a quasi-isomorphism, we must check that the induced map $H^k(i_n^{-1} \mathcal{F}) \to H^k(\underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3])$ on the cohomology sheaves is an isomorphism, which is easily checked on the level of stalks.

**My question is**: (1) Is this attempt correct so far, and (2) is it enough to conclude that $\mathcal{F} = \underline{\mathbb{Q}}[-3]$, using that $BG = \operatorname{colim}_n \mathbb{HP}^n$? Or, (3) is there an easier proof, or is my suspicion just false?

(*Note*: As $EG$ and $BG$ are infinite-dimensional, I could not find any result that $\pi^!$ would exists or has nice enough properties to make the same argument work over $BG$ rather than $\mathbb{HP}^n$.)

Comment: About the short version : the answer is yes, and is specific to $\mathbb N$-indexed unions, see my answer here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447693/gluing-isomorphism-in-derived-categories-along-filtered-colimit/447715#447715

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier argument would be that $R^q\pi_\ast \mathbf Q$ vanishes for $q\notin \{0,3\}$ and has rank $1$ for $q \in \{0,3\}$. Indeed, just check this on stalks. Then the cone of $\mathbf Q\to R\pi_\ast\mathbf Q$ is concentrated in degree $3$. But an object of the derived category with cohomology concentrated in a single degree is isomorphic to its cohomology, by general properties of $t$-structures, so $\mathcal F$ is a shift of a rank $1$ local system. But the local system is necessarily trivial since $\pi_1(BG)=\pi_0(G)$ is trivial.

Taking rational coefficients was not necessary; the statement is true even integrally.

A small final remark: the version of the question that you state in the first paragraph is rather different, since there you assume $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ to be actual sheaves as opposed to objects in the derived category. Maxime's comment is answering the more interesting version of the question, at the derived level.